# Expression Engine & CSS

Tags: php, css, expressionengine

I’ve been learning using Expression Engine. One thing has me stumpted though.

I have a layout that uses a four column grid (see http://training.customstudio.co.uk/services). This uses three CSS classes: one for the column item, one for the last column item, and one for the row to add the horizontal rule.

I’ve used the EE class switch to create the column and column last classes, (see http://training.customstudio.co.uk/portfolio) but I can’t figure out how to get EE to create the row class. I could do this manually, but want the page to be dynamic so if there are 16 items, there will be 4 rows with lines under each.

The code I’ve used is as follows:

```
<div class="content-main">
                        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="portfolio" status="open|Featured" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
                            <div class="{switch='col|col|col|col-last'}">
                                <h4><a href="{title_permalink='portfolio'}">{title}</a></h4>
                                <p>{project_description}</p>
                            </div><!-- /end #col -->
                            {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </div>
<!-- /end #content-main -->
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your column divs in switch statements that contains a 'row' div every four iterations, you should get what you're looking for:

```
                <div class="content-main">
                    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                        {exp:channel:entries channel="portfolio" status="open|Featured" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
                        {switch='<div class="row">|||'}
                        <div class="{switch='col|col|col|col-last'}">
                            <h4><a href="{title_permalink='portfolio'}">{title}</a></h4>
                            <p>{project_description}</p>
                        </div><!-- /end #col -->
                        {switch='|||</div>'}
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this by using the modulus operator which can return the nth item. (https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/the-modulus-operator)

```
<div class="content-main">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="portfolio" status="open|Featured" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
        {!-- Every 4th item add in a div with the class of row --}
        {if count == 1 OR count % 4 == 1}<div class="row">{/if}
        <div class="{switch='col|col|col|col-last'}">
            <h4><a href="{title_permalink='portfolio'}">{title}</a></h4>
            <p>{project_description}</p>
        </div><!-- /end #col -->
        {if count % 5 == 0 OR count == total_results}</div>{/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```